# omitting "for" when using the verb "wish"

Tags: verbs

Is it correct to say this?

> I don't wish everything to be simple, that's not gonna happen (nor do I think it's what we want)

Someone pointed out to me that I should've said,

> I don't wish **for** everything to be simple, that's not gonna happen (nor do I think it's what we want)

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are fine. More idiomatic, in my view, is to use a finite clause, with or without that:

> I don't wish [that] everything was/were simple ...

I put "was/were" because this is one of the contexts where some people would use the old "subjunctive" form *were*. Some people would do so only formal speech, and others wouldn't use it at all.